# Golang and dependencies from private git repositories

Tags: git, go, continuous-integration

Let's assume that I have a Go project that depends on 2 different private repositories from github. I'm using deployment keys, for github authentication. I'm trying to set up CI to build, test and deploy the whole thing.

CI created environment with all 2 deploy ssh keys in place (lets call them `~/.ssh/key1` and `~/.ssh/key2`)

When I run `go build`, it tries to download all dependencies at once. How can I avoid exception that repo does not exist (due to authentication issues)? How would you approach solving that problem?

Comment: Give that key (or a new one only for this purpose) read rights on both repositories.

Comment: Why can you only specify one SSH key? How exactly are you providing the key?

Comment: @fredrik can you explain how would you do that?

Comment: @Flimzy I updated the question to be more readable. Let me know if your questions still persist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with two different keys, you would need to modify the URL of those dependencies in order to reference those separate keys.

That is done through a `~/.ssh/config` (assuming the Jenkins agent is run with the right user, and does have access to `~/.ssh/config`

In that `~/.ssh/config`, you declare two 'Host' entries, each one referencing their own private key:

```yaml
Host repo1
  User git
  Hostname git.server.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key1

Host repo2
  User git
  Hostname git.server.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key2
```

Then make sure the dependency for repo1, for instance, is no longer git@git.server.com:aUser/aRepo but:

```
repo1:aUser/aRepo
```

Comment: Oh. I forgot about that question. Thank you for your answer. I've ended up creating a special github user, granted it all the permissions for repositories needed and used it's private part as default ssh key in my CI environment. I'll accept the answer as a gratitude for you effort. Take care.